# Regex expression to extract everything inside brackets

Tags: c++, regex, string

I need to extract content inside brackets () from the following string in C++;

**#82=IFCCLASSIFICATIONREFERENCE($,'E05.11.a','Rectangular',#28);**

I tried following regex but it gives an output with brackets intact.

```
std::regex e2 ("\\((.*?)\\)");
if (std::regex_search(sLine,m,e2)){
}
```

Output should be:

```
 $,'E05.11.a','Rectangular',#28
```

Comment: Just for general knowledge those are called parentheses.

Comment: `.*?` should be `[^\)]*`, shouldn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are looking for should be in the first matching subexpression, i.e. comprised in the `[[1].first, m[1].second)` interval.

This is because your regex matches also the enclosing parentheses, but you specified a grouping subexpression, i.e. `(.*?)`. Here is a starting point to some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search)

Answer (score 1):

Use lookaheads: `"(?<=\\()[^)]*?(?=\\))"`. Watch out, as this won't work for nested parentheses.

You can also use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\().*(?=\))
```

Try this i only tested in one tester but it worked. It basically looks for any character after a `(` and before a `)` but not including them.