# C++ How to use regex to extract some substrings?

Tags: c++, regex

I've got a string with the following content: "(5 {}) (12 {})"

How can I use regex to extract into two string variables substrings like so:

string1 = "(5 {})"

string2 = "(12 {})"

I'm interested in a pattern which will match and let me extract these substrings when they are not only 2 but even more like so: "(5 {}) (12 {}) (2 {}) (34 {})"

Comment: There are lots of such regex questions to match string between parentheses, haven't you tried anything? See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236767/regex-expression-to-extract-everything-inside-brackets), it could give you a jumpstart.

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for such a simple search.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

[[live]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e72489367e093d9)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s =  "(5 {}) (12 {}) (2 {}) (34 {})";
    std::regex re{R"((\([0-9]+? \{\}\)))"};    
    using reg_itr = std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator>;
    for (reg_itr it{s.begin(), s.end(), re, 1}, end{}; it != end;) {            
        std::cout << *it++ << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::regex_iterator` to iterate through all matches in a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string subject = "(5 {}) (12 {}) (2 {}) (34 {})";
    std::regex pattern(R"((\d+ \{\}))");
    for (auto i = std::sregex_iterator(subject.begin(), subject.end(), pattern); i != std::sregex_iterator(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i->str() << '\n';
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d91947b49f6a326d

Comment: What does the capital R mean in front of the regex pattern string when constructing the regex?